# Words starting with non-letter character in index

Tags: indexing, alphabet

When indexing using `makeidx`, what should I do with terminology starting with a non-letter character? E.g. "†-category", which one would expect appearing before the letter A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `\index{-category@$\dagger$-category}`. The hyphen will make the entry appear before the alphabet.